# Why do I have no client-side response after my Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am working on sending data from a form in ajax with a return of an alert box in case of success or failure.

I already made a topic because my data in $ _POST did not seem to be sent to my php script and the Ajax request did not work. Now the request is well recognized by the server as shown by the network panel :

[datasent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcNcg.png)

I've also made a var_dump($_SERVER) and the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] value is "XML HTTPREQUEST" which indicates that the Ajax request has been launched. Now I have an other problem : I don't have a client-side response: currently the program seems to validate the condition `if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')` and I have an `echo($encoded)` in JSON format as shown below :
[JSON echo php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eegog.png).

Therefore I should have a client-side response, which is not the case actually.

Here are my codes : the form

```html
<form id="contactformpage">
  <div class="messages"></div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="societepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Société</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <input type="text" name="societe" class="form-control" id="societepage" placeholder="Nom de la société"
        aria-describedby="indicsocietepage">
      <small id="indicsociete" class="form-text text-muted"> * Obligatoire </small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="adressepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Adresse</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <input type="text" name="adresse" class="form-control" id="adressepage" placeholder="Adresse">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="codepostaletvillepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Code postal & ville</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codepostaletville" id="codepostaletvillepage"
        placeholder="Code postal & ville">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="contactpage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Nom du contact</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="contactpage" placeholder="Nom du contact">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="telephonepage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Téléphone</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="téléphone" id="telephonepage" placeholder="Numéro de téléphone"
        aria-describedby="indictelephonepage">
      <small id="indictelephonepage" class="form-text text-muted"> * Obligatoire </small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="mailpage" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Adresse mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="mail" id="mailpage" placeholder="Entrez votre adresse mail"
        aria-describedby="indicmailpage">
      <small id="indicmailpage" class="form-text text-muted"> * Obligatoire </small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="selecmarque" aria-describedby="indicmarquepage"> Marque du véhicule
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <select class="form-control" name="marque" style="height:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:1;"
        onchange="generechoixmodele('selecmarque','apreschoixmarquepage','apreschoixmodelepage','nommodelepage','choixmodelepage','choixtypepage');"
        id="selecmarque">
        <option selected> Séléctionnez </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" id="apreschoixmarquepage" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Liste déroulante qui apparait après le choix de la marque -->
    <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="apreschoixmarquepage" aria-describedby="indicmarque"
      id="nommodelepage"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <select class="form-control" name="modele" style="height:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:1;"
        id="choixmodelepage"
        onchange="generechoixtype('selecmarque','choixmodelepage','apreschoixmodelepage','nomtypepage','choixtypepage');">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row" id="apreschoixmodelepage" style="display:none;">
    <!-- Liste déroulante qui apparait après le choix du modèle -->
    <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="apreschoixmodelepage" aria-describedby="indicmarque"
      id="nomtypepage"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <select class="form-control" name="type" style="height:20px;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:1;" id="choixtypepage">
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p> Je souhaite recevoir les catalogues suivants (dynamique)</p>
  <div id="choixcataloguepage">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-6 col-form-label" for="commentairepage">Commentaire</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="commentaire" id="commentairepage" rows="1"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="mail" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Captcha</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 champ">
      <h6> Captcha à rajouter après </h6>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn" id="submitpage">
</form>
```

My jQuery script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submitpage").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'sendform.php',
            data: {
                societe : $("#societepage").val(),
                adresse : $("#adressepage").val(),
                codepostaletville : $("#codepostaletvillepage").val(),
                contact : $("#contactpage").val(),
                telephone : $("#telephonepage").val(),
                mail : $("#mailpage").val(),
                marqueclient : $("#selecmarque").val(),
                modeleclient : $("#choixmodelepage").val(),
                typeclient : $("#choixtypepage").val(),
                commentaire : $("#commentairepage").val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data)
            {
                // data = JSON object that contact.php returns
                // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                    $('#contactformpage').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                    // empty the form
                    $('#contactformpage')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

And my PHP script that returns JSON data when the request has been done :

```php
<?php
/*
THIS FILE USES PHPMAILER INSTEAD OF THE PHP MAIL() FUNCTION
AND ALSO SMTP TO SEND THE EMAILS
 */
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/OAuth.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/POP3.php';
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */
// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$fromEmail = 'lyes.tifoun@hotmail.fr';
$fromName = 'Demo contact form';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendToEmail = 'lyestfn@gmail.com';
$sendToName = 'Lyes Tifoun';
// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// smtp credentials and server

$smtpHost = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$smtpUsername = 'nom_utilisateur';
$smtpPassword = 'mdp';

$fields = array('societe' => 'Société', 'adresse' => 'Adresse', 'codepostaletville' => 'Code postal et ville', 'contact' => 'Nom du contact', 'téléphone' => 'Numéro de téléphone', 'mail' => 'Adresse mail', 'marque' => 'Marque du véhicule', 'modele' => 'Modèle du véhicule', 'type' => 'Type du véhicule', 'commentaire' => 'Commentaire');

$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
try {
    if (count($_POST) == 0) {
        throw new \Exception('Form is empty');
    }

    $emailTextHtml = "<h1>You have a new message from your contact form</h1><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<table>";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailTextHtml .= "<tr><th>$fields[$key]</th><td>$value</td></tr>";
        }
    }
    $emailTextHtml .= "</table><hr>";
    $emailTextHtml .= "<p>Have a nice day,<br>Best,<br>Ondrej</p>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname($smtpHost);
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true));
    $mail->Username = $smtpUsername;
    $mail->Password = $smtpPassword;
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($sendToEmail, $sendToName); // you can add more addresses by simply adding another line with $mail->addAddress();
    $mail->addReplyTo($from);

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = 'test'; //$emailTextHtml;
    $mail->msgHTML($emailTextHtml); // this will also create a plain-text version of the HTML email, very handy

    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        throw new \Exception('I could not send the email.' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
    }

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}
// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Thanks a lot for your responses and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What did you find when you added an error handler to the request? Did you inspect request in browser dev tools network to see if what is sent, status, and what are returned are all as expected? You need to do some basic debugging to isolate source of issue

Comment: Yes I've already checked my Network panel, and all the data returned by the panel matches with what I wrote in the form, the status is 200 so everything is right, I can't understand why I don't have a response.

Comment: So is the success handler firing, or the error handler you added?

Comment: 1. Change your entire php to just `echo 'test';` and see if you get that.  2. You're returning `//else just display the message` but not checking for "just the message" - so in that case `data.type` will be `undefined`.  Add `console.log(data)` as the first line of `success:`

Comment: I have no response either with only `echo 'test';` and I also added console.log(data), but there's nothing in the console after my request.  The condition `//else just display the message` is when the Ajax request hasn't been made which is not the case here. I'm sorry I'm a beginner in Web Development I don't really understand what do you mean by "succcess handler firing" @charlietfl ?

Comment: "success handler firing" means the code inside `success: function() { ...here... }` is getting "hit"/"run", as opposed to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log(errorThrown); }`

Comment: Ok so I just added an error handler : `error: function(xhr, status, error){
              var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
              alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
            }` and when I do my Ajax request, the error handler works and alerts me "Error - 200:OK". So I deleted `dataType:'json',`from my code which was useless because it's already specified in ` header('Content-Type: application/json');` but now, while I'm doing my Ajax request none of success or error is working. Still don't understand why because the status is 200..